# Representations of symmetric (and alternating) groups over finite fields.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, finite-fields, symmetric-groups

I want to learn representations of finite groups (actually in particular symmetric and alternating groups) over finite fields. For now, I am particularly interested in the semisimple case. Can anybody recommend me a suitable text or any other kind of source (notes etc.) to start with?

Comment: It might help if you mentioned something you currently know and something you want to know -- texts and notes take you on a journey, but I'm not sure where you are starting, and the destination you've mentioned is not common. Semisimple representations of symmetric and alternating groups are nearly independent of the field, so you could study them over C (a common destination) and then learn the conversion to finite fields of large characteristic

Comment: @JackSchmidt. Thanks for confirming. I have read some initial chapters from the book on representation theory by Steinberg and "Character theory of finite groups" by Isaacs. So basically I have knowledge of the related terms and definitions and basic set up behind the representation theory of finite groups.

Comment: If you are interested in the symmetric and alternating groups, then probably Sagan's book is the standard choice. The techniques there will produce irreducible representations with integer coefficients, and these can be reduced mod p to get representations over finite fields. They remain irreducible if p is larger than the degree of the symmetric group. For alternating groups, the main issue is that some representations require a field of size p^2 and the representations may involve some square roots and denominators. If p is large enough these reduce mod p (possible into GF(p^2)).

Comment: I believe it can only be 2. In An, the generators of a cyclic subgroup are either all conjugate or fall into two conjugacy classes. In terms of characters, this means either the character value is rational or has two Galois conjugates so lies in a field extension of dimension 2. Over finite fields, the character field determines the representation field, so we either get the character is realizable over GF(p) or GF(p^2). (Over char 0 fields, you can use things like the Frobenius-Schur indicator to go from character field to representing field, but the general case is complicated.)

Comment: I'm not sure. Most of the time they are not irreducible. A5 and A6 each have only one induced irreducible. A7 has none. A8 has 4. A9 has 1. A10 has 2. A11 has none. A12 has 1. A13 has none. The main theorem is Frobenius reciprocity and Mackey's theorem, but in general it is unwieldy. Isaacs's book has some information on primitive characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127576/discussion-between-math-seeker-and-jack-schmidt).